# Error installing hadoop with homebrew

Tags: macos, hadoop, homebrew

I'm trying to get hadoop setup locally on my Mac, but am getting the following error when trying to brew install hadoop:

```
$ brew install hadoop
==> Downloading http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?path=hadoop/core/hadoop-1.1.2/hadoop-1.1.2.tar.gz
==> Best Mirror http://apache.mirrors.pair.com/hadoop/core/hadoop-1.1.2/hadoop-1.1.2.tar.gz

curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404
Error: Download failed: http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?path=hadoop/core/hadoop-1.1.2/hadoop-1.1.2.tar.gz
```

Any ideas what I should do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that `Homebrew` formula for `Hadoop` is outdated, it points to **1.1.2** instead of **1.2.1**. Until the guys from Homebrew fix the bug you can do the following steps in order to install Hadoop 1.1.2:

1. Download manually version 1.1.2 from [http://archive.apache.org/dist/hadoop/core/hadoop-1.1.2/hadoop-1.1.2.tar.gz](http://archive.apache.org/dist/hadoop/core/hadoop-1.1.2/) to any folder in your computer
2. Then move the file `hadoop-1.1.2.tar.gz` to homebrew's temporary folder, if you have not changed it before, it should be located in `/Library/Caches/Homebrew`
3. Finally you can install Hadoop using Homebrew, now brew will find that the file has already been downloaded and will proceed with installation as follows:

   ```
   $ brew install hadoop
   ==> Downloading http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?path=hadoop/core/hadoop-1.1.2/hadoop-1.1.2.tar.
   Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/hadoop-1.1.2.tar.gz
   ==> Caveats
   In Hadoop's config file:
     /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/1.1.2/libexec/conf/hadoop-env.sh
   $JAVA_HOME has been set to be the output of:
     /usr/libexec/java_home
   ==> Summary
     /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/1.1.2: 271 files, 78M, built in 2 seconds
   ```

Answer (score 16):

You have to do a `brew update` first.  It was pointing to the wrong version, but that seems to be fixed now.