# Issue (404) trying to install mariadb via homebrew on mac

Tags: macos, installation, homebrew, mariadb

I want to set up mariadb on my mac and try to get cakephp working with it. I was intending to use homebrew but when I enter:

```
brew install mariadb
```

I get:

```
==> Downloading http://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/mariadb/mariadb-5.3.7/kvm-tarbake-jaun

curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404
Error: Download failed: http://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/mariadb/mariadb-5.3.7/kvm-tarbake-jaunty-x86/mariadb-5.3.7.tar.gz
```

going to this link in a browser redirects me to the mariadb download page. I have looked at the [mariadb page](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/building-mariadb-on-mac-os-x-using-homebrew/) and I saw that while brew is using 5.3.7 the current stable release is 5.5.33a, I tried to change the version with:

```
brew edit mariadb
```

I tried to change the url to the new version but I got this error:

```
Error: Invalid @version
```

I assume this is because the page goes through a signup page...

Question: How can I get a valid version?
Also: I have downloaded the latest version so can i direct brew to the local copy?

Bonus: How can I get the brew formula to look for the latest version (5.5.33a or 10.0.4)?

Answer (score 1):

You get a 404 error if homebrew cannot access the site for whatever reason. Usually the reason for it is that the developers of the software you are trying to install introduced some issues, means it is not Homebrew's fault.

Anyway you can bypass the 404 error by downloading the binaries manually as described in [this answer to the same issue with Hadoop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18240963/error-installing-hadoop-with-homebrew). This also answers your question

> How can I get a valid version? Also: I have downloaded the latest version so can i direct brew to the local copy?

For your "Bonus" question at the end I will cite the [Homebrew FAQ](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/FAQ.md#faq):

> First update the formulae and Homebrew itself:
>
> `brew update`
>
> You can now find out what is outdated with:
>
> `brew outdated`
>
> Upgrade everything with:
>
> `brew upgrade`
>
> Or upgrade a specific formula with:
>
> `brew upgrade $FORMULA`

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, I had the same problem trying to install nginx openssl dependency and it was because for some reason I had no write permissions on `/usr/local`, so I execute:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local
```

That worked for me.

Comment: This won't work in High Sierra. The correct command for High Sierra on up is: `sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*` If you have an outdated version of brew as I did run: `/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"` That should resolve any issues.

Answer (score 0):

I was eventually able to install this via [php-fpm](https://github.com/josegonzalez/homebrew-php)