# Trying to install hadoop on Mac OS Apple Silicon

Tags: macos, hadoop, homebrew, macos-ventura

I am trying to install Hadoop on my Mac OS laptop using Homebrew, however I am getting the following error:

```
╰─ brew install hadoop                                                                                                                ─╯
==> Fetching dependencies for hadoop: openjdk@11
==> Fetching openjdk@11
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/openjdk/11/manifests/11.0.19
Already downloaded: /Users/marin-georgianbadita/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/8077d99d097995ae885c0679ed08a541df9b40e3aa1c8ee13f20e15c61df605c--openjdk@11-11.0.19.bottle_manifest.json
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/openjdk/11/blobs/sha256:1bca4101ca2dc3aedfd920c05ffe5c574836a192ffffdcdf7474d97c818f819a
Already downloaded: /Users/marin-georgianbadita/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/2ceb21ca20d44eddf581818332a0a14ba31d2b7a9e0adfb6c843b4cd7a65cbd5--openjdk@11--11.0.19.arm64_ventura.bottle.tar.gz
==> Fetching hadoop
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/hadoop/manifests/3.3.4-3
Already downloaded: /Users/marin-georgianbadita/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/fdd998ff4385ddabbcc7aa2ff21a3d1c82cf44168e1e047ffae6dece9b5ed4d2--hadoop-3.3.4-3.bottle_manifest.json
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/hadoop/blobs/sha256:9b9c119e86afd1b13cdd51df817742704cc777ac1f90038d7f4f0909b2f1bfa3
################################################################################################################################## 100.0%

Error: hadoop: Failed to download resource "hadoop"

Download failed: https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/hadoop/blobs/sha256:9b9c119e86afd1b13cdd51df817742704cc777ac1f90038d7f4f0909b2f1bfa3
```

OS: MacOS Ventura 13.0.1

I tried the solutions proposed here, but they didn't work: [Error installing hadoop with homebrew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18240963/error-installing-hadoop-with-homebrew)

Any ideas what should/can I do?

Tried `brew update`, try fixing everything that `brew doctor` was complaining about, but nothing worked.